# Expresión regular classpath Silk Central

Tags: regex

Estoy trabajando con Silk Central y necesito añadir en el classpath todos los archivos **.jar** que necesito. Para la aplicación dispongo de cuatro proyectos:`app_EAR`, `app_EJB`, `app_WEB`, `app_TEST` dentro del directorio `app`.

Los archivos .jar que necesito añadir se encuentran en la carpeta lib dentro de su correspondiente protecto:
`C:\app\app_EAR\lib` y `C:\app\app_TEST\lib`

Para añadir los archivos al classpath lo he hecho de la siguiente forma de manera individual:
`app_EAR\lib\*; app_TEST\lib\*`

Pero mi pregunta viene ahora, ¿es posible indicar que incluya todos los archivos **.jar** que encuentre en cualquier carpeta lib dentro del directorio app con cualquier profundidad?

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:
`app*\lib*`  para que busque en cualquier directorio que contenga la palabra app (para que coja `app_EAR` y `app_TEST`) y dentro de cada una uno de ellos la carpeta **lib** que contiene los **.jar**. Silk Central no es capaz de reconocer esta expresión regular.

También lo he intentado así: `**/lib/**.jar` para que encuentre todas las carpetas **lib** independientemente de su profundidad en el directorio, pero tampoco lo reconoce.

Agradezco cualquier aportación. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente no se pude, Java no soporta la búsqueda recursiva en el Classpath cuando Silk Central le pasa la información.